# Python/Pyramid + SQLAlchemy > MySQL: How do I check connection before usage?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I've been informed that the database timeouts (connect, interact, wait) are set at 30s. On that db is a website that people will tend to be idle > 30s.

Using sqlalchemy, I need to check that the mysql connection is still valid before proceeding with querys, otherwise the site errors out.

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649397/how-can-i-check-pooled-connections-in-sqlalchemy-before-handing-them-off-to-my-a), but I'm not pooling connections nor do I have a reliability issue.

Comment: Do you use the `pyramid_tm` transaction manager package? It will do a lot of things for you out of the box, like closing the session automatically after the end of each request.

Answer (score 0):

SQLAlchemy's engines are all implemented as pools, even if they don't actually pool.

Have a read of this article by someone who's been there before you: [SQLAlchemy – MYSQL has gone away](https://mofanim.wordpress.com/2013/01/02/sqlalchemy-mysql-has-gone-away/). In brief:

> The first thing to make sure of is that you set the ‘pool_recycle
>   option’ when using SQLAlchemy ‘create_engine’ function (more [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/core/pooling.html#setting-pool-recycle)).
>   The value of pool_recycle should be less than your MYSQLs wait_timeout
>   value (both are in seconds).
>
> The next and altogether knottier problem is to make sure you correctly
>   manage your session life cycle. It’s well worth carefully reading [this
>   documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/session.html#using-thread-local-scope-with-web-applications). Essentially, you have to make sure that your session is
>   correctly opened when your data request starts and closed when it’s
>   done.

Comment: Thanks. will check that out and reply or mark solved.

Comment: this is hard to read for beginners. i have no place here